# Prevent WPF ViewModel from creating new instance when navigating to other views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I am attempting to prevent my application from deleting a view and then creating a new one each time it's navigated around. I have a dashboard that will run a test program, if I select the settings view, then back to the dashboard, it has deleted the running test and initialized a new view. I need to keep the same view instance alive so that the test can continue to run while the user navigates to the settings view and back again but I cant exactly figure out how to successfully do that. I have attempted making the instance static but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

MainViewModel

```
class MainVM : ViewModelBase
{
        private object _currentView;
        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set { _currentView = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        
        public ICommand DashboardCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand SettingsCommand { get; set; }

        public static DashboardVM DashboardInstance { get; } = new DashboardVM();
        public static SettingsVM SettingsInstance { get; } = new SettingsVM();

        private void Dashboard(object obj) => CurrentView = DashboardInstance;
        private void Settings(object obj) => CurrentView = SettingsInstance;

        public MainVM()
        {
            DashboardCommand = new RelayCommand(Dashboard);
            SettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(Settings);

            // Startup Page
            CurrentView = DashboardInstance;
        }
}
```

ViewModelBase

```
    public partial class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
```

MainView - Navigation

```
            <!-- Navigation Panel -->
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="76">
                <Border Background="#3D5A8A" CornerRadius="10,0,0,10" />
                <StackPanel Height="1200" Width="76">
                    <!-- Dashboard Button -->
                    <nav:Button Style="{StaticResource NavButton_Style}"
                                Command="{Binding DashboardCommand}"
                                IsChecked="True">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="Images/dash_black_50.png"
                                   Style="{StaticResource NavImage_Style}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Dashboard"
                                   Style="{StaticResource NavText_Style}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </nav:Button>
                    <!-- Settings Button -->
                    <nav:Button Style="{StaticResource NavButton_Style}"
                                Command="{Binding SettingsCommand}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="Images/gear_black_50.png"
                                   Style="{StaticResource NavImage_Style}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Settings"
                                       Style="{StaticResource NavText_Style}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </nav:Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

DashboardVM

```
class DashboardVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        enum TestItemStatus
        { 
            Reset,
            Queued,
            InProgress,
            Pass,
            Fail
        }
    
        private readonly PageModel _pageModel;
        private string _StartButtonText,
                        _WaveRelayEthernetText;
        private bool isTestRunning;

        public DashboardVM()
        {
            _pageModel              = new PageModel();
            _StartButtonText        = "Start Test";
            _WaveRelayEthernetText  = string.Empty;
            StartButtonCommand      = new RelayCommand(o => StartButtonClick("StartButton"));
        }

        #region Text Handlers
        public string StartButtonText
        {
            get { return _StartButtonText; }
            set { _StartButtonText = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("StartButtonText"); }
        }
        public string WaveRelayEthernetText
        {
            get { return _WaveRelayEthernetText; }
            set { _WaveRelayEthernetText = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("WaveRelayEthernetText"); }
        }
        #endregion
        
        private bool TestRunning
        {
            get { return isTestRunning; }
            set { isTestRunning = value;
                  if (isTestRunning) { StartButtonText = "Stop Test"; } 
                  else { StartButtonText = "Start Test"; 
                         ResetTestItems();
                    }
                  NotifyPropertyChanged("TestRunning"); 
                }
        }

        public ICommand StartButtonCommand { get; set; }

        private void StartButtonClick(object sender)
        {
            if(TestRunning)
            {
                TestRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                SetTestItemsToQueued();

                MessageBox.Show("Please plug in Tube 1");

                // Start program. 
                TestRunning = true;
                WaveRelayEthernetText = TestItemStatusEnumToString(TestItemStatus.InProgress);
            }
        }

        private string TestItemStatusEnumToString(TestItemStatus temp)
        {
            if (temp == TestItemStatus.Reset) { return string.Empty; }
            else if (temp == TestItemStatus.Queued) { return "Queued"; }
            else if (temp == TestItemStatus.InProgress) { return "In Progress"; }
            else if (temp == TestItemStatus.Pass) { return "Pass"; }
            else if (temp == TestItemStatus.Fail) { return "Fail"; }
            else { return string.Empty; }
        }

        private void SetTestItemsToQueued()
        {
            WaveRelayEthernetText   = TestItemStatusEnumToString(TestItemStatus.Queued);
        }

        private void ResetTestItems()
        {
            WaveRelayEthernetText   = TestItemStatusEnumToString(TestItemStatus.Reset);
        }
    }
```

Image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to to use a `Frame` with a `Page`? I cant remember off the top of my head, but I believe once a Page is instantiated via navigation, it sticks around.

Comment: The other thought, would be to offload the "test program" to a separate singleton class on a different thread than the UI thread (using `async/await`). That way is should be agnostic of what the UI layer is doing.

Comment: Sounds very much like this test is actually the model. Maybe you should explain what this app is doing.

Comment: @Andy I just added the full DashboardVM code and a picture for reference. The top button originally says Start Test, and I click Settings and then back to Dashboard, everything is reset to a new view. The full test isnt added in yet, because I cant yet get my view to stay the same.

Comment: Your posted code does not look suspicous. When you debug your application and put a breakpoint into the constructors, the breakpoint should get hit once. Can you confirm this? If it is hit more than once you would have to provide a minimum but working example that reproduces the issue so that we can review it. Note that although the view model instances are the same the instances of the actual page controls are reinstantiated. In this controls you probably invoke a method on the view model on instantiation/initialization that either resets the state or stops the running test.

Comment: Using the debugger will help you to solve the issue very easily.

Comment: @BionicCode When I have a break point in the dashboard constructor, it gets hit each time I change the view and come back. I can post the full code to GitHub if youd like.

Comment: Next step is to check the call stack when the breakpoint is hit to find the caller site. Alternatively find all references to the DashBoardVM constructor. The goal is to find all constructor calls to remove them. The only constructor call must be inside MainViewModel. Next step is to ensure that MainViewModel is only created once (same procedure as with the DashBoardVM constructor). Because if MainViewModel is constructed multiple times, each instance will create a new DashboardVM. It's important to only have a single MainViewModel instance in your application.

Comment: @BionicCode I have verified that at startup is the only time Main constructor is hit, and then immediately the dashboard constructor is hit. Then Dashboard and Setting constructor gets hit each time the tab is navigated to. Uploaded code if you'd like to look. I appreciate all the thought and assistance. [here](https://github.com/chipbrommer/ConnectionTester)

Comment: @BionicCode could the issue be because my views and view models and binded using DataTemplate ?

Comment: No. Using DataTemplate only creates a new content (view). It does not affect the DataContext - unless on of the views creates instances of view models in XAML or code-behind.

Comment: It will literally create a new view when you navigate, that's what templating does. The code you've shown us only has one place where DashboardVM is instantiated and in any case there's only a get; on DashboardInstance.  Are you definitely not setting CurrentView  any where else?

Comment: @Andy I have included the entire code base in the previous comment to BionicCode. I have a feeling that me using DataTemplate to link the ViewModel to the View is what's causing the issue. I will know shortly as I look into a different way to link the two.

Comment: @Andy I have posted my solution to the problem below. The DataTemplate was my issue - as it was always creating a new view upon each navigation click. I want to sincerely thank you all for your help troubleshooting.

Comment: @BionicCode please see above comment, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My Issue was in the App.xaml, I link a DataTemplate file like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/DataTemplate.xaml" />
```

Inside the data template, I had this code that linked the views to the view models.

```
<ResourceDictionary [...]">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardVM}">
        <view:Dashboard />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SettingsVM}">
        <view:Settings />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I changed that code to link the two to this:

```
<ResourceDictionary [...]>
    <view:Dashboard x:Key="DashboardViewKey"/>
    <view:Settings x:Key="SettingsViewKey"/>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardVM}">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource DashboardViewKey}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SettingsVM}">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource SettingsViewKey}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am now receiveing the expected behavior of being able to navigate without the Dashboard constructor being called, thus the view does not destory and recreate.

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: This is a fix, obviously. But the reason for the abnormal behavior is some severe code smell somewhere, very likely in your views (Dashboard and Settings). It appears like the controls actively set the state of their view models (maybe in their constructors or Loaded event) and therefore overriding the current state of the view model classes. I recommend to fix this instead of hacking a fix. You should solve the original problem.

Comment: You must debug your code. Ensure: a) DashboardVM constructor must be hit only once b) when switching back to Dashboard view no properties of DashboardVM must be set (only getters must get called) c) if a) + b) fail, then find the cause which is likely in the views. Check the flow: what happens inside the Dashboard view when it gets loaded d) if you need help consider to post the code of Dachboard view.